# Finding the largest/smallest object in a python generator/list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a generator `gen` which yields some lists.  I'd like to find the longest list.

I can do

```
max((len(L) for L in gen))
```

which will get me the length of the longest list, but at this point the list is gone to the mists of time.

Alternately I could do

```
maxlength = 0
for L in gen:
    if len(L)>maxlength:
        savelist = L
        maxlength = len(L)
```

But it seems there should be a more pythonic way that avoids the for loop and the if statement.

**edit** just a comment to help others who might search for related problems:
Finding the smallest object with `min` can be done equivalently, and the same approach will work if `gen` is a list instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`max` has a keyword-only argument `key` that will accept a function by which to judge which is largest.

```
result = max(gen, key=len)
```

This would be equivalent to something like:

```
result = [el for _, el in sorted([len(el), el for el in gen])][-1]
# note that `sorted` takes a `key` argument too!
# # result = sorted(gen, key=len)[-1]
```

But obviously MUCH easier to read

Comment: Is that really equivalent? `max` only has to iterate through the items once, not sort it.

Comment: @khelwood no, not at all, but it gives the same result